# Better way to write code for categorization data

Tags: python, pandas

I am working through a Kaggle dataset for wine. There are a lot of represented countries and makes for a messy plot. I want to group those countries into a "Other" category if there are less than a 1000 entries. I got it to work but it seems messy and more code than is needed. Here is the head() and the code that worked which was later used in the plot:

[image: head]

```
values=df["country"].value_counts().values
indicies=df["country"].value_counts().index
other_country = 0
index_greater = []
value_greater = []

for index, value in zip (indicies, values):
    if value > 1000:
        index_greater.append(index)
        value_greater.append(value)
    else:
        other_country=other_country + value
        
index_greater.append("Other")
value_greater.append(other_country)
```

I have also tried writing a nested for loop but my computer is still running through it (+150K wines). Is there a better way to write this code?

```
x = df["country"].value_counts() > 1000

for i in df["country"]:
    for j in x:
        if j == True:
            df["Locale"] = i
        else:
            df["Locale"] = "Other"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: General rule: If you loop over a dataframe, you're probably doing something wrong. Use pandas's built-in filtering methods.